Unknown file called 1
I regularly have a file created without wanting to do so.
It is not traced by git in my project.
It's just called 1 and contains only true
What should I check to know what causes this file to be created ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Also, I'm not really used to Stack, so if my question needs improvement, I would gladly modify =)

Possibly some typo in some shell code that has cmd > file 2>1 instead of cmd > file 2>&1 (and cmd outputs true on stderr). The last modification time of the file will tell you when it was created.

one way to (maybe) find out what creates the file: change its permissions to all zeroes (i.e. chmod a= 1) and see what breaks ;)

Where is this file being created? How is ksh relevant? What is your operating system?

As it was suggested by @stéphane chazelas in the comments, the issue came from a if statement>1; then ...
This was called every time I used any command as this test was in a function called by my PS1
This created a file called 1 containing the result of this if test (often true as stated in my initial question).
